# Is there a chemical which fluoresces only after coming in contact with water?

Tags: fluorescence

I require an easily available chemical compound which in its pure form, does not  fluoresce under UV light. However upon coming in contact with water (at room temperature) it fluoresces under UV light.

Answer (score 1):

Many fluorescent dyes are not fluorescent in their solid states. Fluorescein and similar dyes (rhodamines, eosines) for example. They need to be dissolved in order to be fluorescent (so just wetting them with a bit of water won't work either).

Answer (score 0):

Riboflavin (Vitamin B2) fluoresces under UV light only when in solution, i.e. in contact with water.